# How to create normal map image from camera view?

Tags: normal-map

Good day, I have scene in blender with many objects (picture below) and want create a normal map of this scene from camera view. Is it possible make it in blender (I found only way to create normal map for one object and need make uv map). Mybe it possible if I export scene in different program, like 3d max?
[image: o]

[image]

Example of normal map I need (made in Photoshop with nvidia plugin)

Comment: You can simply enable normal map matcap in the viewport. Don't forget to disable overlays and AO. Then just do Viewport Render Image. https://imgur.com/a/PTcaVCo